# Is there assign_or_inserter/insert_or_assigner in C++20?

Tags: c++, stdmap, c++20

std::inserter suffers from problem that it calls insert that for map is noop if key already exists.
There is [std::map::insert_or_assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign), but I was unable to find an inserter that uses that.

Is there something like this in C++20?

note: I know I can c/p it from somewhere on the SO/internet, I am interested in STL/boost solutions, not c/p implementation from somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no corresponding inserter that use `insert_or_assign`. In fact, the [wording](https://eel.is/c++draft/insert.iterators.general) explicitly says there are only 3 such functions:

> back_­inserter, front_­inserter, and inserter are three functions making the insert iterators out of a container.

Answer (score 4):

#### There is no insert iterator with `insert_or_assign` functionality in the C++20 Standard Library

Insert iterators are governed by [[insert.iterators]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/insert.iterators), and it is particularly described in [[insert.iterators]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/insert.iterators) that the only functions to create iterators

> [...] `back_­inserter`, `front_­inserter`, and `inserter` are three functions making the insert iterators out of a container. [...]

are `back_­inserter`, `front_­inserter`, and `inserter`, which, as covered by [[back.inserter]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/back.inserter), [[front.inserter]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/front.inserter) and [[inserter]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/inserter), respectively, returns `back_insert_iterator`, `front_insert_iterator` and `insert_iterator`, respectively.

As governed by [[back.insert.iter.ops]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/back.insert.iter.ops), [[front.insert.iter.ops]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/front.insert.iter.ops) and [[insert.iter.ops]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/insert.iter.ops), the effect of copy assignment of a `value` to these iterators is as if calling

```
// back_insert_iterator
container->push_­back(value);

// front _insert_iterator
container->push_­front(value); 

// insert_iterator
container->insert(iter, value);
```

respectively. I.e., none of these insert iterators offer the effect of the `insert_or_assign` member functions of  `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` (which was introduced by [N4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), which makes no mention whatsoever regarding insert iterators in the sense of [insert.iterators]).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few hurdles that make it unlikely to be standardised.

`map::insert_or_assign` doesn't have a `value_type` (reference) parameter, which is common across each of `insert`, `push_front` and `push_back`. Remember that `operator=` only has one parameter, so you'll have to construct a pair to assign to your proxy.

It would be desirable to forward either or both of key and value, how do you distinguish passing `const std::pair<const Key, Value> &`, `std::pair<Key &&, const Value &>` etc.

There are only 2 standard containers that have `insert_or_assign`, `map` and `unordered_map`. Every container has `insert`, and all the sequence containers have one or both of `push_front` or `push_back`.

Comment: I couldn't help trying it out. Perhaps it could look something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Wcfdeq)? (updated to work in MSVE)

Comment: @TedLyngmo if I understand this answer correctly problem is that if you have copy(std::make_move_iterator(vec_src.begin()), ... will it effectively move values to the map instead of doing a copy...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl That sounds like what one would want? Like `std::move(foo.begin(), foo.end(), insert_or_assign_iterator(bar));`, but in an awkward way so to speak?

Comment: @TedLyngmo IDK, hard for me to imagine all cases in how people might want to use this assigner... but why note do copy_if with move iterators(there is no move_if)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl True. My idea was just a start. It make be infeasible to create something that would fit into the standard properly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not saying it's impossible, but that it doesn't belong in `std`. Something like that could go in `boost`